# Datagridview title font in windows forms in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, fonts, title

How can I change the font of title of a Data grid view in Windows Form in C#? Or how can I change column names font in a dataGridView in Windows Form in c#? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's Windows Forms right ?

Comment: yes. It's Windows Forms.

Comment: googled this within 2sec... really, why bother to ask such question? it costs more time to write the question then do some research first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume You have some columns and You want to change the header of first column

```
MyDataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "My title";
```

To change the font in header check this:

```
// ("Arial", 20") means it will use Arial font with 20em size.
dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 20);
```

Comment: I want to change the font of the header of whole datagridview

Comment: You also asked about column Name which i answered. If You want to change headers font i'm pretty sure You need to iterate through all cells in first row and change its font property

Comment: How can I insert the font in /* SOME FONT */ would you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Set Font and Color Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2akwyy7(v=vs.90).aspx)

there is HeaderText property in Column object,

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    grid.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 15);
    grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "First Column"; 
    //..............
}
```

[DataGridViewColumn.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.name.aspx)

Comment: where can I declare the specific font?

Comment: @hamed i updated my answer i wish it will help you !!

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle. OP asked about fonts for header not for whole DataGridView

Comment: @MajkeloDev yes !! you are right . But the MSDN link which i provide give the whole information about the manipulation of font in datagridview :)